# How to get SQL Server Compact 4.0 Database content query?

Tags: sql-server, migration, sql-server-compact

I need to migrate data to a SQL Server 2014 database from an existing SQL Server CE 4.0 database. I'm having difficulty because my computer runs SQL Server 2012 so I'm not able to port the data via a graphical wizard.

I am able to run scripts on all databases. I just don't know how to perform a the data migration without a graphical interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my ExportSqlCe command line tools to export the schema and data, and then use sqlcmd to run the resulting script against a SQL Server 2014 database https://exportsqlce.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Command%20line%20utilities&referringTitle=Documentation